# can i insert Data At Specific Time like 11:50 Tonight in SQLite in android Oreo?

Tags: android, android-studio, alarmmanager, android-8.0-oreo, background-service

**i will try but thats not work properly**
*so please give some exmple that work in Oreo and Insert Data at 11:30*

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("requestCode",1);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,55);
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (alarmMgr != null) {
            alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);


        }
```

Comment: You should go with job scheduling or work manager

Comment: thank you for comment but you have parfect example of job Scheduling becouse i was try but that not accurate. @MohitSuthar

Comment: Yes, you are right, have you tried work manager?

Comment: no @MohitSuthar